# Website not resizing to mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a website up and running but for some reason most of the pages are not resizing to mobile phones.

Homepage, everything is fine except for the carousel. On the other pages, the images and most of the text are just everywhere.

I ve tried to use

```
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 300px !important ;}
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 300px !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 300px !important; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 400px !important ;}
}
@media, (min-width: 800px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 600px !important ; }
}
```

and

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

but the carousel doesn't resize. Any suggestions would be appreciated

my HTML:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <title>Home | XLevelRetail</title>

     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
     <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->       

     </head><!--/head-->

      <body class="homepage">






     <section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
        <div class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0"  class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>

             </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
           <div class="item active" style="background-image:url(images/slider/667.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">World Class Point Of Sales Solutions </h1>
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">From a single store mum and pop business to a 1,000 store chain, we provide retail management solutions that provide a perfect fit and grows as the retailer grows</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->

                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/erp.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">ERP Solutions</h1>
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">The back end counts, from Accounting solutions to full ERP solutions we provide solutions to fit each organization size</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->

                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/tam.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Time & Attendance Solutions</h1>
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">Easy to use cloud based Time & Attendance solutions that integrate with all payroll services</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->

                <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/banners.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">The Future of Retail</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->

                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/ecom.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Omni Channel Ecommerce Set Up</h1>
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">When we implement ecommerce we do not close our eyes to the backend, and we take into cognizance all points of contacts for the customer. Such channels include retail stores, online stores, mobile stores, mobile app stores, telephone sales and any other method of transacting with a customer</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->
            </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
         </div><!--/.carousel-->
         <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
         </a>
         <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
         </a>
         </section><!--/#main-slider-->





my css
     <style>
        .services-wrap {
          padding: 15px 30px;
          background: #fff;
          border-radius: 4px;
          margin: 0 0 40px;
          height: 180px;
        }

        .int {
            width: 250px;
        }

        /*.int > h3 {*/
            /*font-size: 12px;*/
        /*}*/
        @media (min-width: 200px) {
            div.item > img{ height: 300px !important ;}
        }

        @media (min-width: 300px) {
            div.item > img{ height: 300px !important; }
        }

        @media (min-width: 400px) {
            div.item > img{ height: 300px !important; }
        }
        @media (min-width: 600px) {
            div.item > img{ height: 400px !important ;}
        }
        @media (min-width: 800px) {
            div.item > img{ height: 600px !important ; }
        }
      </style>
   #main-slider .carousel .item {
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    left: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block !important;
     height: 100%;
```

Comment: link to website : www.xlevelretail.com

Comment: A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (problem reduced to a bare minimum) in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is better. You website will be unavailable or changed eventually rendering this question worthless.

Comment: looking into html of your page, you can notice that there are no images inside of `div.item`, so your rules won't work

Answer (score 1):

You have bad media querys - missing the `screen and` part, and there's a comma in the last one for some reason... You're also missing some spaces between `img` and `{`, most likely causing the browser to derp.

Use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  div.test > img {
      height: 300px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  div.test > img {
      height: 300px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  div.test > img {
      height: 300px !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  div.test > img {
      height: 400px !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  div.test > img {
     height: 600px !important;
  }
}
```

instead. You can read up more on media querys [here](http://devdocs.io/css-media-queries/).

Comment: oops just noticed the errors, adjusted the media querys with yours but it didnt work

Comment: @Ben that suggests your spacing derps out the browser. Edited the answer to include proper spaces.